# Conditionals that use \ref

Tags: conditionals, ref

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\section{First Section}\label{sect_1}

Question: Is this Section \ref{sect_1}?

IFX Answer:
\ifx\ref{sect_1}1 YES \else NO\fi.

IF Answer:
\if\ref{sect_1}1 YES \else NO\fi.

\end{document}
```

Both answers are NO. I assume that when the conditional is evaluated, the value of `\ref{sect_1}` is not known (or `\ref` is not expanded). Is there a way to get the right answer (maybe, using the `.aux` file)?

Comment: `\ifx\ref{` compares the command `\ref` to the token `{` `\if\ref` compares the first two non expandable tokens the expansion of `\ref`  Look at the `zref` suite of packages from Heiko for a version of `\ref` more amenable to testing.

Comment: @samcarter: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @GuM Apparently my answer did not answer real question of the OP. But without knowing what the OP is actually trying to do, I would need a better crystal ball.

Comment: @samcarter: As far as I understand the question, yours *is* an answer.  I’d only use `\getrefnumber`, instead of setting a temporary counter.

Comment: @GuM As far as I understand the question as it is written on this site, I also think my answer is an answer, I have just the feeling, that the question we see is not the true question. I'm going to undelete my answer, maybe it will help some future users.

Comment: @GuM And thanks for the `\getrefnumber` suggestion, that is really much simpler :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `refcount` package allows you to access the the number stored in the label. You can use this to compare it either to hard coded values or to counters like the current section. (Thanks a lot to @GuM for the suggestion to use `\getrefnumber` instead of `\setcounterref`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}\label{sect_1}

Question: Is this Section \ref{sect_1}?


\ifnum\value{section}=\getrefnumber{sect_1}
    yes
\else
    no
\fi

\section{Second Section}\label{sect_2}

Question: Is this Section \ref{sect_1}?

\ifnum\value{section}=\getrefnumber{sect_1}
    yes
\else
    no
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe the example is too minimal. I want to use the values provided by the \ref command in conditional statements (typesetting different things based on the value of some label).

Comment: @digital-Ink Well, `\value{foo}` will give you the content of label (if a single number --  but there are workarounds for multiple numbers as well). You can compare it to whatever you want, I just used `\value{section}` because I thought you wanted to know if this is the section of the label or another.